# update-grub caused non-booting configuration

Tags: grub2

I ran `update-grub` and after this, the system will not boot. It gets stuck in a blank screen. Possible before GRUB, possibly in GRUB that just shows a blank screen.

I would normally get a text menu where I can select Ubuntu-20.04.

If I boot on USB I can mount the `/boot` partition, and the `grub/grub.cfg` looks reasonable. But there may be a change that I am unaware of.

How can I rescue this?

I have the feeling I can just boot on a USB-disk with GRUB and then edit the GRUB config to choose another harddisk to "exec" the GRUB installed on that drive.

Maybe there is even a specialized boot-rescue disk, that will simply give me a list of devices to "exec" to. `boot-repair` cannot repair the disk, because `/` is zfs on lvm on an encrypted block device.

The system uses legacy (not UEFI).

Comment: When booting GRUB from USB, you can hit `c` to enter command-line mode. You should be able to load `configfile (hdX,msdosY)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Does that result in a working system? Apart from that, have you tried [Super GRUB 2 Disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/supergrub2/)?

Comment: The question is, what did you do immediately before `update-grub`. My guess is you changed something in `/etc/default/grub` or `/etc/grub.d`. I would try undoing that change.